# After Minting X amount of NFTs change Price

Tags: solana-program, rust, nft, mint, time

I am very new to Solana. I have a client's rust Program, it mint NFTs and allow admin who deployed the Solana Program to change the price. I have to add functionality to change the Sol price once X amount of NFTs is minted or the current sale time ended. Any code snippet that might be helpful for me or from where to get started?

Deployed Program on Devnet: https://explorer.solana.com/address/BkdiSpTX4Kumr92TZtxZnQWsNH4sjnjs1hTfzXdV8Uef?cluster=devnet

This is my first time reading rust code. I think that's the code in smart contract that i need to focus on.

```
      ctx: Context<MintNFT>,
      creator_key: Pubkey,
      // _uri: String,
      title: String,
      _nonce_minting: u8,
      _nonce_user_minting: u8,
  ) -> ProgramResult {
          // set user minting info
      let mut _max_num = ctx.accounts.minting_account.bl_max;
      let mut _price = ctx.accounts.minting_account.bl_price;
      let mut _state = 3;

//sale type 1: OG (pre-sale before whitelist sale)
      match ctx.accounts.minting_account.og_list.iter().position(|og| { *og == ctx.accounts.payer.key().to_string() }) {
              Some(_index) => {
                  _max_num = ctx.accounts.minting_account.og_max;
                  _price = ctx.accounts.minting_account.og_price;
                  _state = 1;
              }
              None => {}
          } 

//sale type 2: WL(white list sale)
      match ctx.accounts.minting_account.wl_list.iter().position(|og| { *og == ctx.accounts.payer.key.key().to_string() }) {
              Some(_index) => {
                  _max_num = ctx.accounts.minting_account.wl_max;
                  _price = ctx.accounts.minting_account.wl_price;
                  _state = 2;
              }
              None => {}
          } 

//sale type 3: bl (public sale)
      match ctx.accounts.minting_account.bl_list.iter().position(|og| { *og == ctx.accounts.payer.key.key().to_string() }) {
              Some(_index) => {
                  _state = 5;
              }
              None => {}
          } 
      
      if ctx.accounts.minting_account.max_teacher <= ctx.accounts.minting_account.cur_num
          || ctx.accounts.minting_account.cur_stage != _state || ctx.accounts.user_minting_counter_account.cur_num >= _max_num {
          return Err(MyError::InvalidOperation.into());
      }
      // msg!("Jerry!");
      // msg!(&_price.to_string());
      // **ctx.accounts.payer.to_account_info().try_borrow_mut_lamports()? -= _price;
      // **ctx.accounts.owner.to_account_info().try_borrow_mut_lamports()? += _price;
      msg!("Initializing Mint Ticket");
      let cpi_accounts = MintTo {
          mint: ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info(),
          to: ctx.accounts.token_account.to_account_info(),
          authority: ctx.accounts.payer.to_account_info(),
      };
      msg!("CPI Accounts Assigned");
      let cpi_program = ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info();
      msg!("CPI Program Assigned");
      let cpi_ctx = CpiContext::new(cpi_program, cpi_accounts);
      msg!("CPI Context Assigned");
      token::mint_to(cpi_ctx, 1)?;
      msg!("Token Minted !!!");
      let account_info = vec![
          ctx.accounts.metadata.to_account_info(),
          ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info(),
          ctx.accounts.mint_authority.to_account_info(),
          ctx.accounts.payer.to_account_info(),
          ctx.accounts.token_metadata_program.to_account_info(),
          ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
          ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(),
          ctx.accounts.rent.to_account_info(),
      ];
      msg!("Account Info Assigned");
      let creator = vec![
          mpl_token_metadata::state::Creator {
              address: creator_key,
              verified: false,
              share: 100,
          },
          mpl_token_metadata::state::Creator {
              address: ctx.accounts.mint_authority.key(),
              verified: false,
              share: 0,
          },
      ];
      
      let new_uri = format!("{}{}{}",ctx.accounts.minting_account.base_uri, ctx.accounts.minting_account.cur_num , ".json");

      msg!("Creator Assigned");
      let symbol = std::string::ToString::to_string("symb");
      invoke(
          &create_metadata_accounts_v2(
              ctx.accounts.token_metadata_program.key(),
              ctx.accounts.metadata.key(),
              ctx.accounts.mint.key(),
              ctx.accounts.mint_authority.key(),
              ctx.accounts.payer.key(),
              ctx.accounts.payer.key(),
              title,
              symbol,
              new_uri,
              Some(creator),
              1,
              true,
              false,
              None,
              None,
          ),
          account_info.as_slice(),
      )?;
      msg!("Metadata Account Created !!!");
      let master_edition_infos = vec![
          ctx.accounts.master_edition.to_account_info(),
          ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info(),
          ctx.accounts.mint_authority.to_account_info(),
          ctx.accounts.payer.to_account_info(),
          ctx.accounts.metadata.to_account_info(),
          ctx.accounts.token_metadata_program.to_account_info(),
          ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
          ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(),
          ctx.accounts.rent.to_account_info(),
      ];
      msg!("Master Edition Account Infos Assigned");
      invoke(
          &create_master_edition_v3(
              ctx.accounts.token_metadata_program.key(),
              ctx.accounts.master_edition.key(),
              ctx.accounts.mint.key(),
              ctx.accounts.payer.key(),
              ctx.accounts.mint_authority.key(),
              ctx.accounts.metadata.key(),
              ctx.accounts.payer.key(),
              Some(0),
          ),
          master_edition_infos.as_slice(),
      )?;
      msg!("Master Edition Nft Minted !!!");
      ctx.accounts.user_minting_counter_account.cur_num += 1;
      ctx.accounts.minting_account.cur_num += 1;
      Ok(())
  }

}
#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(_nonce_minting: u8)]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Change the Sol price once X amount of NFTs is minted or the current sale time ended`.
You have a global counter of minted NFTs - `ctx.accounts.minting_account.cur_num`. So to change price once X amount of NFTs is minted, you should also check this `cur_num` and depending on the amount of minted NFTs, modify the price. For the time u have timestamps. For example:

```
let cur_num = ctx.accounts.minting_account.cur_num.clone();
// If more than 1000 NFTs were minted, we double the price
if cur_num > 1000 {
_price = _price * 2;
};
// If some timestamp was passed, we triple the price
if Clock::get().unwrap().unix_timestamp > 16_655_521_949 {
_price = _price * 3;
};
// If timestamp === 
msg!(&_price.to_string());
**ctx.accounts.payer.to_account_info().try_borrow_mut_lamports()? -= _price;
**ctx.accounts.owner.to_account_info().try_borrow_mut_lamports()? += _price;
```

So here is the basic - u compare current time and current amount of minted NFTs. Now u could extend your however u want.

You store mint configuration in `MintingAccount`, so you should consider adjusting it and add some additional data you need.

For example, for timestamps, you could add

```
pub og_end_timestamp: i64,
pub wl_end_timestamp: i64,
pub public_end_timestamp: i64
```

to your MintingAccount struct, so the program will have access to the timestamps of end of the mint process. And with this info you might do what you want to - as far as u asked about the price, once the sale ended:

```
let public_end_timestamp = ctx.accounts.minting_account.public_end_timestamp;
let current_timestamp: i64 = Clock::get().unwrap().unix_timestamp;
if public_end_timestamp < current_timestamp {
_price = _price * 2;
};
```

Same about amounts of minted NFTs. You could add any amount barriers u want to, for example, you could add something like that to your MintingAccount:

```
pub total_minted_stages: Vec<TotalMintedStage>,
```

where TotalMintedStage is

```
#[derive(AnchorSerialize, AnchorDeserialize, Clone)]
pub struct TotalMintedStage {
    pub min_minted_nfts: u64,
    pub max_minted_nfts: u64,
    pub price: u64
}
```

And so with this additional info in ur MintingAccount, you might iterate over the list of those TotalMintedStages and find the one (if exists) that is the best for you:

```
let cur_num = ctx.accounts.minting_account.cur_num.clone();
// Find any stage that is matching current amount of minted NFTs
match ctx.accounts.minting_account.total_minted_stages.iter().position(|stage| { *stage.min_minted_nfts <= cur_num && *stage.max_minted_nfts >= cur_num }) {
              Some(index) => {
// And if found - modify the price
                  _price = ctx.accounts.minting_account.total_minted_stages[index].price;
              }
              None => {}
          }
```

So here are just some examples of how u could do it. But it's always up to you!

And I believe github examples and Anchor, Rust, Solana & Metaplex docs will be the most helpful for u.